# Why can't I bind dates in query string with GET parameters?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, data-binding, razor-pages

I am using ASP.NET Core 3.1. I am trying to bind dates in a query string to a PageModel using GET. Here is my query string:

```
?id=15+startDate=1900-01-01+endDate=1900-01-01
```

Here is the signature of my OnGet:

```
public void OnGet(int id, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
```

The values are always `0, 1/1/0001 00:00:00, 1/1/0001 00:00:00` respectively.

If I remove the dates and just pass the id, it works fine. Why do the dates in the query string break everything including the id? I have also tried changing the data types from `DateTime` to `string` and it still breaks with the string parameters always being `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The separator for parameters in a query string is `&`, not `+` as your example has. Corrected:

```
?id=15&startDate=1900-01-01&endDate=1900-01-01
```

An arguably better approach with datetime parameters is to accept them as strings, then use [`DateTime.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparse?view=net-5.0) to parse with control over expected format. That way you'll always have the opportunity to inspect the string value provided and decide if you want to convert it to a `DateTime`, and how.

Comment: Grrrr. Not sure what I was thinking when I put in the pluses. I have been bouncing between so many languages lately. I should have realized this right away. It's amazing how many times you look at something and not see the obvious. Thanks for pointing that out, now I feel really dumb. By the way, I was considering the string approach and parsing as well and will probably end up including time zone information or ISO dates to make sure that local dates are handled properly.